# Automatically clear the temporary files in window

Tags: windows, windows-10

Currently, I manually clear the temporary files by clicking the keys - `window + r`
and then run these commands one by one -  `%temp%`, `temp`, `prefetch`, `cleanmgr`.

Can you please give me some insight if is there any way to clear these files automatically daily with some window configuration or maybe with corn job when the system starts it clears all these temporary files? What would be the easier and best way to accomplish this so I don't need to run this manually every time?

Thanks

Comment: Why not configure a scheduled task?

Comment: @spikey_richie, can you please share some references on this?

Comment: Perhaps try this:    ............   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085250/how-to-schedule-a-daily-task-to-run-a-batch-file

Comment: No, if you don't know how to use task scheduler then go read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the commands you currently manually run into a batch file or a powerscript script file and run it automatically at a given time or when the user logs on using Windows task scheduler. Look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page